# Digipot for DC motor

Tags: dc-motor, digital-potentiometer

I am going to use a 3V DC motor (operating voltage 1.5 to 4.5V DC) and [MSP430G2553](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/msp430g2513.pdf) microcontroller. So which digital potentiometer should I use to control the speed of the DC motor?

Comment: Why do you think a digital pot is a good way to control a motor?

Comment: At first I was planning to use a PWM but I was asked to use a digital pot which I have no idea about it. Can you give some suggestions on which digipot should I use? Can I use MCP4231?

Comment: PWM is the right thing to do here. A digital pot is going to require a transistor working in its linear region, and at that point, you have a heating element at low speeds.

Comment: I can't use the PWM:( So, we can't only use a digital pot to control the motor? Is the transistor a 'must'?

Comment: No digital pot is going to be able to sink enough current to drive a motor. Read some datasheets. If I were you, I would research until I could coherently present my case as to why using a digital pot is insane, and go bark up trees with that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digital potentiometers are designed to control low power signals that must be passed through a variable resistance, eg. the volume control in an audio amplifier. Most are only capable of handling 1~2mA, not nearly enough to power an electric motor which could draw several Amps.

Now that doesn't mean you can't use a digital pot, but you *will* need something to boost its output current. A bipolar transistor is the obvious choice, since it is a current amplifier. However it also has limitations. High power transistors generally have low current gain, so you will probably need at least two transistors to get enough gain. Also some voltage loss may occur due to biasing requirements.

Here is a circuit that uses an MCP4231-502 and an NPN and PNP transistor to control motor voltage at up to 3 Amps. The 2N4401's typical current gain (Hfe) is about 180 at 100mA collector current, and the TIP42's is about 30 at 3A, for a total of 180 x 30 = 5400. Therefore at 3A output current the load on the MCP4231 should be well under 1mA.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOLjiM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

One possible problem with this simple circuit is that bipolar transistors need about 0.6V between Base and Emitter to turn on; so Q1 won't turn on until the potentiometer gets up to 0.6V, and Q2 absorbs about 0.6V from the motor supply. As a result, this circuit can only supply a maximum of about 2.4V to the motor. If you need to control motor voltage over a wider range then a few extra components will be required.

Comment: Thank u very much for ur help:) One question please, The microcontroller has the output of 3V dc, so is another dc source(V2) is needed for the transistor?

Comment: The motor could draw a lot of current, so you should use a separate power supply for it (eg. Two AA Alkaline cells in series). To avoid ground loop problems, connect the negative supply lead directly to the motor, then connect another wire from motor negative to the digital pot and MCU grounds.